# intellij: is there selective undo feature as in emacs?

Tags: intellij-idea

Basically, in emacs. we can undo changes only in a selected region. Its a a very useful feature. Wonder whether intellij has it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be a feature request submitted to Jetbrains, not a SO question.

Comment: i am ok if you know the feature is not in intellij (let us know how you know it)

Comment: Well, he is asking whether it is possible or not, not requesting the feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't. The equivalent in IntelliJ is the local history. You can right click on a file, choose local history->show history. You can then see the changes made over time and select individual lines/sections to remove or reapply.